# Why did the first two reviewers reject, and the last make a not even cosmetic change?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Brief history of the post:

The user answered a question in C# suggesting a comparison of `foo.Count(x)==0`. Another user commented suggesting changing `Count` to `Any`, because the latter method is quicker.

The original answerer accepted and edited his answer to `foo.Any(x)==0`. `foo.Any()` returns a boolean. In C# you can't apply the `==` operator to `boolean`and `int`, so the answer would generate a compile-time error. I suggested an edit to `!foo.Any(x)`, which is the correct way to do it. My edit got two negative votes made by people who I don't think have read the answer properly, then was made by another user. Why did this happen?

Link to the review in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10119381

Notice the votes say my edit doesn't improve the accuracy of the post, even though the original answer wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Your edit *wasn't* officially rejected...

Comment: Well, it was voted by 2 people as not making the post easier to read, find, or more accurate. It does make the post more accurate.

Comment: the edit review queue is weird...... people accept a LOT of cr*p they shouldn't and reject a lot of very good stuff as well

Comment: You can't expect to make edits such that only those with knowledge of the subject are going to review it. Until you reach 2000 rep, leaving a comment for those is the best way to deal with it. If you change code that requires knowledge, expect rejections.

Comment: @BillWoodger Sorry, but I think that defeats the whole purpose of reviewing. That's simply depressing. If they don't have the knowledge to review, why are they reviewing?

Comment: "review" is a jargon word. In this context, it probably doesn't mean what you think. It certainly doesn't imply any specific technical knowledge for the post in question. How would that work?

Comment: @BillWoodger: It would work wonderfully. If, you know, too many people didn't have an unholy terror of "skip". I'm not holding my breath waiting to see that change.

Comment: @Deduplicator well, I meant how would it work as it currently is. If everyone skips what they don't know, minor tags are never going to get any edits approved. If you've a suggestion there for "peer review" of changes to code in posts, that's a feature request (or an operational change request). Since, as I understand it, changes to code by <2k users should be rare, I don't see much likelihood of a change which completely stuffs low-volume tags and asks more of knowledgeable users.

Comment: Since StackOverflow is a rep based system there's an obvious improvement here to the "Reviewers don't understand what they're reading" problem - prefer reviewers that have high scores in the tagged subjects of the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It wasn't.

Two people voted for rejection because of the useless word-change, which is a hoot. They should have rejected for "attempting to reply" or "radical change", *if at all*, after carefully weighing your change to the code. Or they should have skipped if they wanted to avoid that work.

And that code-change is actually a clarification which should be accepted, so it all worked out in the end, with the last one choosing to *improve* your suggestion.

The last editor probably made that pro-forma change in order to "improve" and make sure the edit gets applied.

Comment: Well, the useless word change was a necessary evil, because otherwise I wouldn't be able to correct a wrong code on the site, and the answer didn't have anything else to be altered.

Comment: Sure, I didn't say *you* did anything wrong there. Just a comment on the two rejecters...

Comment: Sure, thanks for the answer. About your last edit, I fail to see where did he improve my suggestion, since he made the exact same edit I had suggested.

Comment: @jose if you look at the markdown, you can see he removed a blank line at the end.

Comment: And he probably only did *that*, because he suspected the robos would reject (which was evidently a good guess).

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. I had tried to add those spaces, but the algorithm enforcing the rules wasn't fooled by them. Guess I've forgotten to remove them later.